# How to check a check box in Capybara test when using simple_form

Tags: capybara, rspec-rails

Trying to test some functionality in a simple page and I am getting this error when using page.check:

```
    Failures:

  1) searching for stores serving a taco and a sauce: Adobada tacos with Chile de Arbol sauce
     Failure/Error: page.check 'Adobada'

     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find checkbox "Adobada"
     # ./spec/views/store_search_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<%= simple_form_for :stores, url: stores_path, method: :get do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :tacos, 'Select Tacos to Find: ', class: 'label' %>
  <div class='taco-select checkboxes'>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :tacos, Taco.order(:name), :id, :name,
      :include_hidden => false, :item_wrapper_class => 'checkbox_container' %>
  </div>

  <%= f.label :salsa, 'Select Sauces to Find: ', class: 'label' %>
  <div class='salsa-select checkboxes'>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :salsas, Salsa.order(:name), :id, :name,
      :include_hidden => false, :item_wrapper_class => 'checkbox_container' %>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit 'Search!' %>

<% end %>
```

And this is my test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'searching for stores', %(serving a taco and a sauce:) do

  scenario 'Adobada tacos with Chile de Arbol sauce' do
    visit root_path

    page.check 'Adobada'
    page.check 'Chile de Arbol'

    click_button 'Search!'

    expect(page).to have_content "Store"
    expect(page).to have_content 'City'

  end
end
```

I would like to test that when some checkboxes are set to true a certain content is rendered in the page.
Don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Please show the actual html from the page -- the erb doesn't show us whats actually in the page

Comment: It is shown under the section "Here is my HTML".

Comment: It is shown above under the label "Here is my HTML".

Comment: That's erb, not html - page.html will return the actual html that makes up the page, or open in a browser, and view the source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use an ID to check a checkbox. You can just use the label on the checkbox. Say you have a checkbox like this

```
<label for="...">
  <input type="checkbox" name="...">Something</label>
```

You 'check' it in capybara like so

```
it "" do
  page.check 'Something'
end
```

Official docs on this can be found [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#check-instance_method)

Answer (score 7):

Try with these, they should work for you:

```
find(:css, "#YOUR_CHECKBOX_ID").set(true)
```

or

```
page.check('YOUR_CHECKBOX_ID')
```

or simply

```
find('THE CSS SELECTOR OF YOUR CHECKBOX').click
find(:xpath, 'THE XPATH OF YOUR CHECKBOX').click
```

Comment: Looking at the code, I don't know which is 'YOUR_CHECKBOX_ID' in my case. Same thing for 'THE XPATH OF YOUR CHECKBOX'. I am aware of these methods "find" and "page,check" but don't know which are the ID or the XPATH of those check boxes.

Comment: Inspect your webpage (with google chrome for example) and look for your checkbox. It will have an 'id', and if you want to find its css selector or xpath, just right click on it, then 'copy' and choose one between 'copy css selector' or 'copy xpath'

Comment: Your first example would require a # in front of the id since you're using a :css selector find an id  and page.check doesn't take a symbol as it's first parameter - to use page.check it would be  `page.check('YOUR_CHECKBOX_ID')`  - and calling .click on the checkbox is not the same as calling .check  -- check will leave a checkbox selected if it already is - click would toggle it.